# How can you gracefully exit 'rake preview' in Octopress?

Tags: octopress

At the moment, I am using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit `rake preview`. Is there a graceful way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the source](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/Rakefile)

```
trap("INT") {
    [jekyllPid, compassPid].each { |pid| Process.kill(9, pid) rescue Errno::ESRCH }
    exit 0
}
```

Only when you change the script you could make it respond to something else. But <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is just fine.

`trap("INT")` does the magic: as soon as Ctrl+C is pressed the part between the curly braces is executed. That code simply kills all preview processes.

Comment: Thanks! I had seen this line in the source but wasn't sure what it was saying... I guess Process.kill(9) is equivalent to ctrl C ?

Comment: @JetBlue - no, `trap("INT")` does the magic; as soon as Ctrl+C is pressed the part between the curly braces is executed. That code simply kills all preview processes.